# language for Turing machine, {w#w | w ∈ {0,1}*}

Tags: turing-machines

Recently, I am studying a computation theory and got a question regarding turning machine.

let {w#w | w ∈ {0,1}*} be the language of a turning machine.  it will accept, for example, 01#01.

however, if we have a turning machine accepting the language of {w#w | w ∈ {0,1}}.  What string will it accept?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a practical computer programming question. It is a question about understanding a theoretical computer. Try cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RaymondChen By that argument, you could close all questions under the tag `turing-machines`. There'll always be some overlap between SO and CS. How about ignoring this tag (and other theory-heavy ones like `np`) if it bothers you?

Comment: @Mo B. Thanks for your support.  If this kind of question does not allow to be here, why could I find a tag with "turing-machines" ?   I am sure the tag exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, `w` can only be `0` or `1`, so the language is finite:

```
L = { 0#0, 1#1 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, so does it mean the * is like a "closure" symbol?

Comment: and also, will it accept 01#01 or 10#10? thank you

Comment: @thcuwl Yes, * means 0 or more repetitions, so `{0, 1}* = { ε, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 100, ... }`. The second language only contains 2 elements, as stated in my answer.